# android app integration with facebook review compulsory?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have written a code to login using facebook button sdk 4.0. I am able to login/logout. There is an activity for user from where user can share their locally saved picture to facebook. Sharing is possible if native facebook app is installed. But not in case facebook is not installed. So I tried to use ShareApi for sharing pictures via web view. But it requires publish actions permission. So I just written following code to get permission. It opens a window where it ask for per ok and cancel with my app name. After pressing ok button it always falls in onCancel case automatically. 
I have read somewhere that you need to submit your app for review to facebook team in order to take publish actions permission. Is this only reason i am not getting success after trying almost 18 hours.?? Please help me friends.

```
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
            LoginManager loginManager = LoginManager.getInstance();
            loginManager.logInWithPublishPermissions(activity,permissionNeeds);
            loginManager.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    System.out.println("onSuccess" + loginResult);
                    sharePhotoToFacebook();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    System.out.println("onCancel");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    System.out.println("onError"+error);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Are you testing your app with email id as mansion in Roles of Facebook Developer Portal ? if not , test your app with email configured with your developer portal for testing purpose it will work fine with it.

Comment: I have used Facebook SDK 4.4.0 and try this.See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987007/facebook-graph-api-android/32987870#32987870)

Comment: @Kapil thanks for your reply. This app is already published on goggle play. But as per client requirement changed. So i am adding this features as addition. So As per your answer if i will add myself as developer then the problem will solve for my account at least.

Comment: @kapil yup after adding my self as developer of app. It solved my problem. I am now getting publish_actions permission. Thanks again.

Comment: pleasure to help @AshutoshSrivastava now bro if it work fine you have to add your app for review so that all users can use that functionality.

Comment: Yes you need to submit for review. Voting to close this question since this is not technical issue with your code